# Webpack: Need an appropriate loader to handle this file type error

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, webpack-loader

I'm new to webpack and I'm trying to install **Webpack Bundle Analyzer** on my project and I'm getting this error.

I'm following this guide: https://www.codementor.io/@drewpowers/high-performance-webpack-config-for-front-end-delivery-90sqic1qa#7-webpack-bundle-analyzer

```
C02ZD1HBLVDR user$ node_modules/.bin/webpack --profile --json

{
  "errors": [
    "./src/index.js 47:2\nModule parse failed: Unexpected token (47:2)\nYou may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.\n| \n| ReactDOM.render(\n>   <Provider store={store}>\n|     <MCApolloProvider>\n|       <AuthWrapper>"
  ],
  "warnings": [
    "configuration\nThe 'mode' option has not been set, webpack will fallback to 'production' for this value. Set 'mode' option to 'development' or 'production' to enable defaults for each environment.\nYou can also set it to 'none' to disable any default behavior. Learn more: https://webpack.js.org/concepts/mode/"
  ],
  "version": "4.19.1",
  "hash": "9574a566eab3b6564571",
  "time": 84,
  "builtAt": 1583223758357,
  "publicPath": "",
```

**This is my webpack.config.dev.js:**

```
const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');
const resolve = require('resolve');
const webpack = require('webpack');
const PnpWebpackPlugin = require('pnp-webpack-plugin');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const CaseSensitivePathsPlugin = require('case-sensitive-paths-webpack-plugin');
const InterpolateHtmlPlugin = require('react-dev-utils/InterpolateHtmlPlugin');
const WatchMissingNodeModulesPlugin = require('react-dev-utils/WatchMissingNodeModulesPlugin');
const ModuleScopePlugin = require('react-dev-utils/ModuleScopePlugin');
const getCSSModuleLocalIdent = require('react-dev-utils/getCSSModuleLocalIdent');
const ManifestPlugin = require('webpack-manifest-plugin');
const ModuleNotFoundPlugin = require('react-dev-utils/ModuleNotFoundPlugin');
const ForkTsCheckerWebpackPlugin = require('fork-ts-checker-webpack-plugin-alt');
const typescriptFormatter = require('react-dev-utils/typescriptFormatter');
const paths = require('./paths');
const getClientEnvironment = require('./env');
const MonacoWebpackPlugin = require('monaco-editor-webpack-plugin');
const BundleAnalyzerPlugin = require('webpack-bundle-analyzer').BundleAnalyzerPlugin;

const MONACO_DIR = path.resolve(__dirname, 'node_modules', 'monaco-editor');

// Webpack uses `publicPath` to determine where the app is being served from.
// In development, we always serve from the root. This makes config easier.
const publicPath = '/';
// `publicUrl` is just like `publicPath`, but we will provide it to our app
// as %PUBLIC_URL% in `index.html` and `process.env.PUBLIC_URL` in JavaScript.
// Omit trailing slash as %PUBLIC_PATH%/xyz looks better than %PUBLIC_PATH%xyz.
const publicUrl = '';
// Get environment variables to inject into our app.
const env = getClientEnvironment(publicUrl);

// Check if TypeScript is setup
// Although our project is not utilizing TypeScript yet,
// we are keeping it in case we change our mind.
const useTypeScript = fs.existsSync(paths.appTsConfig);

// style files regexes
const cssRegex = /\.css$/;
const cssModuleRegex = /\.module\.css$/;
const sassRegex = /\.(scss|sass)$/;
const sassModuleRegex = /\.module\.(scss|sass)$/;

// common function to get style loaders
const getStyleLoaders = (cssOptions, preProcessor) => {
  const loaders = [
    require.resolve('style-loader'),
    {
      loader: require.resolve('css-loader'),
      options: cssOptions,
    },
    {
      // Options for PostCSS as we reference these options twice
      // Adds vendor prefixing based on our specified browser support in
      // package.json
      loader: require.resolve('postcss-loader'),
      options: {
        // Necessary for external CSS imports to work
        ident: 'postcss',
        plugins: () => [
          require('postcss-flexbugs-fixes'),
          require('postcss-preset-env')({
            autoprefixer: {
              flexbox: 'no-2009',
            },
            stage: 3,
          }),
        ],
      },
    },
  ];
  if (preProcessor) {
    loaders.push(require.resolve(preProcessor));
  }
  return loaders;
};

// This is the development configuration.
// It is focused on developer experience and fast rebuilds.
// The production configuration is different and lives in a separate file.
module.exports = {
  mode: 'development',
  // You may want 'eval' instead if you prefer to see the compiled output in DevTools.
  devtool: 'cheap-module-source-map',
  // These are the "entry points" to our application.
  // This means they will be the "root" imports that are included in JS bundle.
  entry: [
    // Include an alternative client for WebpackDevServer. A client's job is to
    // connect to WebpackDevServer by a socket and get notified about changes.
    // When you save a file, the client will either apply hot updates (in case
    // of CSS changes), or refresh the page (in case of JS changes). When you
    // make a syntax error, this client will display a syntax error overlay.
    // You can replace the line below with these two lines if you prefer the stock client:
    // require.resolve('webpack-dev-server/client') + '?/',
    // require.resolve('webpack/hot/dev-server'),
    require.resolve('react-dev-utils/webpackHotDevClient'),
    // Finally, this is our app's code:
    paths.appIndexJs,
    // We include the app code last so that if there is a runtime error during
    // initialization, it doesn't blow up the WebpackDevServer client, and
    // changing JS code would still trigger a refresh.
  ],
  output: {
    // Add /* filename */ comments to generated require()s in the output.
    pathinfo: true,
    // This does not produce a real file. It's just the virtual path that is
    // served by WebpackDevServer in development. This is the JS bundle
    // containing code from all our entry points, and the Webpack runtime.
    filename: 'static/js/bundle.js',
    // There are also additional JS chunk files if you use code splitting.
    chunkFilename: 'static/js/[name].chunk.js',
    // This is the URL that app is served from. We use "/" in development.
    publicPath,
    // Point sourcemap entries to original disk location (format as URL on Windows)
    devtoolModuleFilenameTemplate: info => path.resolve(info.absoluteResourcePath).replace(/\\/g, '/'),
  },
  optimization: {
    // Automatically split vendor and commons
    // https://twitter.com/wSokra/status/969633336732905474
    // https://medium.com/webpack/webpack-4-code-splitting-chunk-graph-and-the-splitchunks-optimization-be739a861366
    splitChunks: {
      chunks: 'all',
      name: false,
    },
    // Keep the runtime chunk seperated to enable long term caching
    // https://twitter.com/wSokra/status/969679223278505985
    runtimeChunk: true,
  },
  resolve: {
    // This allows you to set a fallback for where Webpack should look for modules.
    // We placed these paths second because we want `node_modules` to "win"
    // if there are any conflicts. This matches Node resolution mechanism.
    modules: ['node_modules'].concat(
      // It is guaranteed to exist because we tweak it in `env.js`
      process.env.NODE_PATH.split(path.delimiter).filter(Boolean),
    ),
    // These are the reasonable defaults supported by the Node ecosystem.
    // We also include JSX as a common component filename extension to support
    // some tools, although we do not recommend using it.
    extensions: paths.moduleFileExtensions.map(ext => `.${ext}`).filter(ext => useTypeScript || !ext.includes('ts')),
    alias: {
      '@src': `${paths.appSrc}`,
      '@vendor': `${paths.appVendor}`,
      'styled-components': path.resolve(__dirname, '..', 'node_modules', 'styled-components'),
    },
    plugins: [
      // Adds support for installing with Plug'n'Play, leading to faster installs and adding
      // guards against forgotten dependencies and such.
      PnpWebpackPlugin,
      // Prevents users from importing files from outside of src/ (or node_modules/).
      // This often causes confusion because we only process files within src/ with babel.
      // To fix this, we prevent you from importing files out of src/ -- if you'd like to,
      // please link the files into our node_modules/ and let module-resolution kick in.
      // Make sure our source files are compiled, as they will not be processed in any way.
      // new ModuleScopePlugin(paths.appSrc, [paths.appPackageJson]),
    ],
  },
  resolveLoader: {
    plugins: [
      // Also related to Plug'n'Play, but this time it tells Webpack to load its loaders
      // from the current package.
      PnpWebpackPlugin.moduleLoader(module),
    ],
  },
  module: {
    strictExportPresence: true,

    rules: [
      // Disable require.ensure as it's not a standard language feature.
      { parser: { requireEnsure: false } },

      // First, run the linter.
      // It's important to do this before Babel processes the JS.
      {
        test: /\.(js|mjs|jsx)$/,
        enforce: 'pre',
        use: [
          {
            options: {
              formatter: require.resolve('react-dev-utils/eslintFormatter'),
              eslintPath: require.resolve('eslint'),
            },
            loader: require.resolve('eslint-loader'),
          },
        ],
        include: [paths.appSrc, paths.appVendor],
      },
      {
        // "oneOf" will traverse all following loaders until one will
        // match the requirements. When no loader matches it will fall
        // back to the "file" loader at the end of the loader list.
        oneOf: [
          // "url" loader works like "file" loader except that it embeds assets
          // smaller than specified limit in bytes as data URLs to avoid requests.
          // A missing `test` is equivalent to a match.
          {
            test: [/\.bmp$/, /\.gif$/, /\.jpe?g$/, /\.png$/],
            loader: require.resolve('url-loader'),
            options: {
              limit: 10000,
              name: 'static/media/[name].[hash:8].[ext]',
            },
          },
          // Process application JS with Babel.
          // The preset includes JSX, Flow, and some ESnext features.
          {
            test: /\.(js|mjs|jsx|ts|tsx)$/,
            include: [paths.appSrc, paths.appVendor],
            loader: require.resolve('babel-loader'),
            options: {
              customize: require.resolve('babel-preset-react-app/webpack-overrides'),

              plugins: [
                [
                  require.resolve('babel-plugin-named-asset-import'),
                  {
                    loaderMap: {
                      svg: {
                        ReactComponent: '@svgr/webpack?-prettier,-svgo![path]',
                      },
                    },
                  },
                ],
              ],
              // This is a feature of `babel-loader` for webpack (not Babel itself).
              // It enables caching results in ./node_modules/.cache/babel-loader/
              // directory for faster rebuilds.
              cacheDirectory: true,
              // Don't waste time on Gzipping the cache
              cacheCompression: false,
            },
          },
          // Process any JS outside of the app with Babel.
          // Unlike the application JS, we only compile the standard ES features.
          {
            test: /\.(js|mjs)$/,
            exclude: /@babel(?:\/|\\{1,2})runtime/,
            loader: require.resolve('babel-loader'),
            options: {
              babelrc: false,
              configFile: false,
              compact: false,
              presets: [[require.resolve('babel-preset-react-app/dependencies'), { helpers: true }]],
              cacheDirectory: true,
              // Don't waste time on Gzipping the cache
              cacheCompression: false,

              // If an error happens in a package, it's possible to be
              // because it was compiled. Thus, we don't want the browser
              // debugger to show the original code. Instead, the code
              // being evaluated would be much more helpful.
              sourceMaps: false,
            },
          },
          // "postcss" loader applies autoprefixer to our CSS.
          // "css" loader resolves paths in CSS and adds assets as dependencies.
          // "style" loader turns CSS into JS modules that inject <style> tags.
          // In production, we use a plugin to extract that CSS to a file, but
          // in development "style" loader enables hot editing of CSS.
          // By default we support CSS Modules with the extension .module.css
          {
            test: cssRegex,
            exclude: [cssModuleRegex, MONACO_DIR],
            use: getStyleLoaders({
              importLoaders: 1,
            }),
          },
          // Adds support for CSS Modules (https://github.com/css-modules/css-modules)
          // using the extension .module.css
          {
            test: cssModuleRegex,
            exclude: MONACO_DIR,
            use: getStyleLoaders({
              importLoaders: 1,
              modules: true,
              getLocalIdent: getCSSModuleLocalIdent,
            }),
          },
          // Opt-in support for SASS (using .scss or .sass extensions).
          // Chains the sass-loader with the css-loader and the style-loader
          // to immediately apply all styles to the DOM.
          // By default we support SASS Modules with the
          // extensions .module.scss or .module.sass
          {
            test: sassRegex,
            exclude: sassModuleRegex,
            use: getStyleLoaders({ importLoaders: 2 }, 'sass-loader'),
          },
          // Adds support for CSS Modules, but using SASS
          // using the extension .module.scss or .module.sass
          {
            test: sassModuleRegex,
            use: getStyleLoaders(
              {
                importLoaders: 2,
                modules: true,
                getLocalIdent: getCSSModuleLocalIdent,
              },
              'sass-loader',
            ),
          },
          // "file" loader makes sure those assets get served by WebpackDevServer.
          // When you `import` an asset, you get its (virtual) filename.
          // In production, they would get copied to the `build` folder.
          // This loader doesn't use a "test" so it will catch all modules
          // that fall through the other loaders.
          {
            // Exclude `js` files to keep "css" loader working as it injects
            // its runtime that would otherwise be processed through "file" loader.
            // Also exclude `html` and `json` extensions so they get processed
            // by webpacks internal loaders.
            exclude: [/\.(js|mjs|jsx|ts|tsx)$/, /\.html$/, /\.json$/],
            loader: require.resolve('file-loader'),
            options: {
              name: 'static/media/[name].[hash:8].[ext]',
            },
          },

          {
            test: /\.css$/,
            include: MONACO_DIR,
            use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader'],
          },
        ],
      },
      // ** STOP ** Are you adding a new loader?
      // Make sure to add the new loader(s) before the "file" loader.
    ],
  },
  plugins: [
    new MonacoWebpackPlugin({ languages: ['json'] }),
    // Generates an `index.html` file with the <script> injected.
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      inject: true,
      template: paths.appHtml,
    }),
    // Makes some environment variables available in index.html.
    // The public URL is available as %PUBLIC_URL% in index.html, e.g.:
    // <link rel="shortcut icon" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/favicon.ico">
    // In development, this will be an empty string.
    new InterpolateHtmlPlugin(HtmlWebpackPlugin, env.raw),
    // This gives some necessary context to module not found errors, such as
    // the requesting resource.
    new ModuleNotFoundPlugin(paths.appPath),
    // Makes some environment variables available to the JS code, for example:
    // if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development') { ... }. See `./env.js`.
    new webpack.DefinePlugin(env.stringified),
    // This is necessary to emit hot updates (currently CSS only):
    new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin(),
    // Watcher doesn't work well if you mistype casing in a path so we use
    // a plugin that prints an error when you attempt to do this.
    new CaseSensitivePathsPlugin(),
    // If you require a missing module and then `npm install` it, you still have
    // to restart the development server for Webpack to discover it. This plugin
    // makes the discovery automatic so you don't have to restart.
    new WatchMissingNodeModulesPlugin(paths.appNodeModules),
    // Moment.js is an extremely popular library that bundles large locale files
    // by default due to how Webpack interprets its code. This is a practical
    // solution that requires the user to opt into importing specific locales.
    // https://github.com/jmblog/how-to-optimize-momentjs-with-webpack
    // You can remove this if you don't use Moment.js:
    new webpack.IgnorePlugin(/^\.\/locale$/, /moment$/),

    new BundleAnalyzerPlugin('./reports/plain-report.txt'),
    // Generate a manifest file which contains a mapping of all asset filenames
    // to their corresponding output file so that tools can pick it up without
    // having to parse `index.html`.
    new ManifestPlugin({
      fileName: 'asset-manifest.json',
      publicPath,
    }),
    // TypeScript type checking
    useTypeScript &&
      new ForkTsCheckerWebpackPlugin({
        typescript: resolve.sync('typescript', {
          basedir: paths.appNodeModules,
        }),
        async: false,
        checkSyntacticErrors: true,
        tsconfig: paths.appTsConfig,
        compilerOptions: {
          module: 'esnext',
          moduleResolution: 'node',
          resolveJsonModule: true,
          isolatedModules: true,
          noEmit: true,
          jsx: 'preserve',
        },
        reportFiles: [
          '**',
          '!**/*.json',
          '!**/__tests__/**',
          '!**/?(*.)(spec|test).*',
          '!src/setupProxy.js',
          '!src/setupTests.*',
        ],
        watch: [paths.appSrc, paths.appVendor],
        silent: false,
        formatter: typescriptFormatter,
      }),
  ].filter(Boolean),

  // Some libraries import Node modules but don't use them in the browser.
  // Tell Webpack to provide empty mocks for them so importing them works.
  node: {
    dgram: 'empty',
    fs: 'empty',
    net: 'empty',
    tls: 'empty',
    child_process: 'empty',
  },
  // Turn off performance processing because we utilize
  // our own hints via the FileSizeReporter
  performance: false,
};
```

This is the code where it's failing:

```
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import MCApolloProvider from '@src/shared/contexts/apollo-context';

ReactDOM.render(
 failing here  --->   <Provider store={store}>
    <MCApolloProvider>
      <AuthWrapper>
        <SocketProvider>
          <FeatureFlagsProvider>
            <SPFProvider config={SPF_CONFIG}>
              <App />
            </SPFProvider>
          </FeatureFlagsProvider>
        </SocketProvider>
      </AuthWrapper>
    </MCApolloProvider>
  </Provider>,
  document.getElementById('root') || document.createElement('div'), // for testing
);
```

**Package.json**

```
"devDependencies": {
    "@babel/cli": "^7.1.2",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-nullish-coalescing-operator": "^7.7.4",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-optional-chaining": "^7.7.4",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.1.0",
    "@testing-library/react": "^9.1.3",
    "babel-plugin-lodash": "^3.3.4",
    "babel-plugin-transform-react-remove-prop-types": "^0.4.18",
    "cypress": "^3.8.0",
    "dom-testing-library": "^4.1.1",
    "enzyme": "^3.9.0",
    "enzyme-adapter-react-16": "^1.7.1",
    "eslint": "^6.8.0",
    "eslint-config-airbnb": "^17.1.0",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^3.3.0",
    "eslint-config-react-app": "^3.0.5",
    "eslint-loader": "2.1.1",
    "eslint-plugin-cypress": "^2.8.1",
    "eslint-plugin-flowtype": "2.50.1",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.14.0",
    "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "^6.1.2",
    "eslint-plugin-prettier": "^3.0.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.11.1",
    "eslint-plugin-react-hooks": "^1.6.0",
    "eslint-plugin-security": "^1.4.0",
    "git-branch-is": "^2.1.0",
    "husky": "^1.3.1",
    "jest": "^24.0.0",
    "jest-styled-components": "^6.3.3",
    "lint-staged": "^8.1.0",
    "lolex": "^4.0.1",
    "prettier": "^1.15.3",
    "pretty-quick": "^1.8.0",
    "react-styleguidist": "^9.0.9",
    "react-testing-library": "^7.0.1",
    "redux-devtools-extension": "^2.13.7",
    "redux-mock-store": "^1.5.3",
    "waait": "^1.0.5",
    "wait-on": "^3.3.0",
    "webpack-bundle-analyzer": "^3.6.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.3.11"
  },
```

**I'm trying to understand what Loader I'm missing and How can I add it?**

**Been struggling for the past half day. Would appreciate any inputs**

Comment: I don't think you are missing any loaders. The issue is in the index.js file which contains JSX only, no loaders required for that. Judging by the error message, it may be the case that in your npm script, you forgot to specify the mode for webpack. But, obviously you wouldn't make that mistake. So, can you please share the scripts portion of your package.json. That might help in finding the issue.

Answer (score 0):

If you set up react with webpack, you need to install @babel/preset-react, add this to the .babelrc file and you have to

```
      import React from "react"
```

on top of each file that you are using jsx.

here is .babelrc configuration. it should be placed in the root.

```
{
  "presets": ["@babel/preset-env", "@babel/preset-react"],
  "plugins": [
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-nullish-coalescing-operator",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-optional-chaining",
    "babel-plugin-lodash",
    "babel-plugin-transform-react-remove-prop-types"
  ]
}
```

.babelrc should be in the root of the project.